# Download Office 2013 without Windows Live

Tags: microsoft-office, windows-live, microsoft-office-2013

I need to install Office 2013 on an end user's PC but am being asked to log into Windows Live to retrieve the install. Is there any workaround for this as I don't want the install associated with my account.

Comment: Is there a reason why it wasn't bought from the store, or is this coming from the Windows Marketplace similar? How about having the user create a Windows Live account and use theirs?

Comment: It seems like a hoop I shouldn't have to jump through! And it's a retail "code only" purchase.

Comment: I've set up a company Live account to use.

Comment: @MilesHayler - I was able to install my copy of Office 2013 without connecting a Microsoft Account. Of course I also used the backup media instead of the online installer.  What makes you think the install will be associated with your Microsoft Account?  Its only going to be used to configure the default settings from personal experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have the user create a Windows Live account and use theirs, or have a live account specific for company use.

Comment: Went with setting up a company account. If they need to reinstall, they'll just have to come back to us. Chances are they would have done anyway. Didn't realise it didn't automatically set up SkyDrive at the same time on installation which was another concern.

Comment: @There's a regkey to turn off automatic sign in, if you're interested in that http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715259.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Its perfectly fine to download and install without having to signup for the Microsoft Account annoyance. But these solutions are obviously highly impopular by MS, since they want you in their system, as new versions of Windows 8 is getting more deeply integrated with `Skydrive`, `Cloud`, `App Store` etc, and what have you. You can access direct download links at their related third-party site, [HeiDoc.net](http://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/73-office-2013-direct-download-links), which is the service provider that manages Microsoft's software download platforms. They write:

> With the release of Office 365, Microsoft Office is now tightly
>   integrated with  the Cloud, Skydrive, the Windows Live services etc.
>   As a result of this change,  the majority of the download versions of
>   the Office 2013 applications is no  longer delivered as publicly
>   available files on the Digital River servers, but  directly streamed
>   onto the client devices from Microsoft's servers. There is  also an
>   alternative download source with the backup images directly from 
>   Microsoft. Both download sources make up a complete repository or all
>   Office  2013 downloads.

It's a shame (and paradox) that MS continuously make it harder to use their products, by making their paying users jump through all these hoops. For more details about their various licensing options look at [this thread](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/299174-microsoft-office-2013-product-key-card-requires-account).

Answer (score 0):

no there is no way to direct download that edition of office 2013, could you please check your license that is accepted on office 2013 standard, because 90% they are similar product with different type of licensing. because there is direct Download for that edition if you want.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more specific. Office 2013 Home and Student. And those don't look like official links!